# Can Grunt run a .cshtml (asp.net mvc) file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, gruntjs

I have a project that I am working on that has:

- backend done with ASP.NET MVC ( the web API)
- frontend done with Angular-JS , Grunt and Node JS.

The question posed here for the team was:

- Have a part of the page ( a menu, navbar for example) being controlled my ASP.MVC and the rest (content) to be generated/controlled by angular.

Would NodeJS be able to do this (frankenstein-ish) task?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **YES**. 
A good starting example would be to take a look at `yeoman` [`generator-aspnetmvc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetmvc)

```
$ npm install -g yo //install yeoman

$ npm install -g generator-aspnetmvc //install generator-aspnetmvc from npm

$ mkdir YourProject

$ cd YourProject

$ yo aspnetmvc  //initiate the generator
```

The project in this example should give you an idea about how your grunt file can be configured to work with MVC applications.